# How to filter pound signs in a file using python?

Tags: python

a file content just like this:

```
##this is the comment

but this is not comment '####', LOL   # this is a normal comment
```

I just want to filter all comments and get the filtered content, But I don't know how to avoid to filter the pound signs which are not comments.

```
fileLines = [line.strip() for line in file if '#' != line[0] ]
```

this code just can filter the comment sign which is the first character of a line.

the result I want is just like the following line:

```
but this is not comment '####', LOL
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import shlex
filelines = [' '.join(shlex.split(line,True)) for line in file]
```

See the [shlex docs](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#module-shlex) for more information.

Comment: this is what I want. Is there any other solutions which don't use shlex? I mean , more simple way

Comment: @remy: How much more simple can you get?  It's one stdlib function call.

Comment: +1, this is a really simple way to strip out comments, however with just this you will lose some formatting like the single quotes surrounding `####` in the sample, so some additional work may be necessary.

Comment: @remy this task isn't that simple to reinvent your own 'simple' wheel.  using standard library is much better for this task because it was made for solving alike tasks. if only you don't want to rewrite this library from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
fileLines = [line for line in file if not line.lstrip().startswith('#')]
```

But I have a hard time reading your question (the examples are formatted in some weird way), so I don't really know if that's what you want.

Comment: thank you, I just don't know what is the normal way to format, sorry. Your code could filter the first line comment, but the second comment still left.  <br>but this is not comment ####, LOL   # this is a normal comment</br>

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution that uses the [tokenize](http://docs.python.org/library/tokenize.html) module to strip out comments but maintain all other formatting (unlike shlex):

```
import tokenize

fileLines = []
printed = set()
for toknum, _, (line, col), _, data in tokenize.generate_tokens(file.readline):
    if toknum == tokenize.COMMENT:
        printed.add(line)
        if col != 0:
            fileLines.append(data[:col].strip())
    elif (toknum in (tokenize.NL, tokenize.NEWLINE) and
          line not in printed):
        fileLines.append(data.strip())
```

Using a file with the text you provided, `fileLines` would become the following:

```
['', "but this is not comment '####', LOL"]
```

Note that the line that starts with the comment is completely removed, but the empty line without the comment is kept.  For the line with the comment partway through, none of the formatting is changed at all.

If you also wanted to remove blank lines, you could just change the `elif` condition to `toknum == tokenize.NEWLINE and location[0] not in printed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do things like this - but note this will not work if there is a quote in the comment:

```
import re    
for line in file:
      print re.sub("\#+[\w\s\d]+$", "", l)
```

If you really want to do it without shlex I think you would have to count in from the begining of the line and record when quotes are open